# How to find resource issuing request in Kubernetes cluster by IP address?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

Update:

What I am trying to achieve: I have the IP address of a cluster resource (10.1.239.128 in the examples below) and want to figure out to which POD/service/... it belongs.

---

I set up a Kuebernetes cluster using Microk8s running, among others, vault and cert-manager via Helm charts. In two of the PODs created for vault and cert-manager, I get multiple the following log entry:

```
> kubectl logs pod/cert-manager-webhook-6787f645b9-s5fxl

http: TLS handshake error from 10.1.239.128:37763: EOF
```

```
> kubectl logs pod/release-name-vault-0

http: TLS handshake error from 10.1.239.128:48609: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority
```

I am struggling with finding out where these requests come from.

I tried:

- `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces`
- `kubectl get endpoints  --all-namespaces`
- `kubectl get endpointslices  --all-namespaces`
- `ping -a 10.1.239.128` using from a POD created using [netshoot](https://github.com/nicolaka/netshoot)

to figure out from where the requests are coming from, but to no luck. The ip address is not listed or resolved to a DNS name to further investigate.

Any further ideas of how to get the resource issuing the request or further debug this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I misunderstood your requirements, so I deleted them. Although the `-n` flag in tcpdump can be helpful `Don't convert addresses (i.e., host addresses, port numbers, etc.) to names`

Comment: @P.... Sorry for the confusion, I updated the question to make it clearer. However, I got some good insights and new tools from your previous post and comment for my further endeavors. Thank you for that!

Comment: Not an answer, but "may" point toward the direction.  `k api-resources  -oname |while read r; do echo -n "$r ----> "; k get $r -A -o yaml |grep -oPz '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+';echo "" ; done`, try grep your IP, if you find it, half of the task is done.  
`

Comment: Wow, I was not aware of all the resource types that get IP addresses. Found it, it is either a ipamhandle, ipamblock, or blockafinity.Thank you very much for your support, was a big step forward! Was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround, not the finest way of doing it, but it may help to get in the right direction:

```
kubectl api-resources  -oname |while read r;
do 
     echo -n "$r ----> ";
     kubectl get $r -A -o yaml |grep -oPz '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+';
     echo "" ;
done
```

Assuming the IP, you are searching for is a cluster resource.